# space frequency representation of images in matlab

Tags: image-processing

How can I plot a space-frequency representation of an image in MATLAB?
I know that there is a function called `spectrogram()` but it is useful just in the case of one-dimentional signals and not for images. Can someone help me please?

Comment: what is "time" in the context of images? I'm a little confused... I think you should explain *why* (for *what purpose*) you want this!

Comment: A crude way would be to find the STFT of each column to get a 3-D array (row x column-time x column-frequency). You could then loop over every 2-D subset of this array (column-time x column-frequency) and find the STFT of each row. The result would be a 4-D array (row-time x row-frequency x column-time x column-frequency).

Comment: An STFT expresses frequency as time evolves. A static image is constant in time. You have to have something that evolves “like” time. Maybe scale akin to a Laplacian decomposition or perhaps a sequence of intensity level sets

Comment: @StanleyPawlukiewicz The connection of the STFT to time is arbitrary - it could be distance or any other unit of measurement. I think the OP is asking about the STFT of 2-D signals, though it is poorly worded.

Comment: You can depict time-frequency of a pixel of a **video** but in case of an image I am not sure

Comment: Well, to more explain my problem: I'm doing an extension of the work of some researchers that related to study a one dimentional signal by exploiting the theory of image processing of its time-frequency representation(spectrogram). Therefore, in my work I want to generalize this concept and analyse images through there time frequency representations or space spatial frequency representation.
****the existing:
1-D signal -----Spectrogram---> 2-D representation(Image)
****What I want to do:
2-D image-----  tool(what I'm searching for) --> 4-D representation

Comment: If you have an *image* (i.e. not a *video*), then why would *time* be involved? That's what we are wondering. What would be the 4 dimensions you talk about? Frequency, space, and...?

Comment: @lfz You should probably edit your question to remove the use of the word "time" and just ask about a STFT applied to both dimensions of a 2-D array. I don't why people are getting hung up on that word, but they are.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pseudo matlab code for doing it.

```
X = 2D_image;
Y = 3D_array_for_storage;
Z = 4D_array_for_final_result;
for m = 1 : Num_cols_in_X
  Y(m,:,:) = spectrogram(X(:,m));
end
for m = 1 : size(Y,2)
  for n = 1 : size(Y,3)
    Z(:,:,m,n) = spectrogram(Y(:,m,n));
  end
end
```

The result is a 4-D array that is row-time x row-freq x col-time x col-freq. (It does not have to be time and frequency per se. The units of the axes are arbitrary; they could be second, meters, volts, etc.) As for how you display, I have no idea what's best for your case. A movie could display any three of the dimensions. Perhaps you could tile the fourth dimension? It would all depend of the specifics.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried to implement this code in matlab but I had this error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in ImageRepresentation (line 6)
  Y(m,:,:) = spectrogram((X(:,m))');  I think because spectrogram(X(:,m)) is a two dimension and we storage the result in Y(m,:,:) which is a 3 dimensions. So, have you any idea how can i deal whith this type of error plz ?

Comment: That error means that the size of the second and third dimensions of `Y` do not match the size of the output from `spectrogram(X(:,m))`.

Comment: AnonSubmitter85 can yu tell me please how can I deal with this error?

Answer (score 1):

Code-specific implementations are not standard here. I hereby provide a more generic answer.

Frequency, on the Fourier setting, ought to be the dual variable of the original signal's ordinal (meaning: with an order) variable: 1D in time or space, or... something else in an higher dimension. Dual here means that properties in both domains can be very similar or symmetric, like the inversion formulas, or the modulation/shift relations.

Ordinal could be time, space, etc. Let us call it "short-term" to limit ambiguity. The [standard 1D formula is (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform):

$$\mathrm{STFT}\{x(t)\}(\tau,\omega) \equiv X(\tau, \omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(t) w(t-\tau) e^{-j \omega t} \, dt $$

But you can easily convert it you a 2D transform, converting $t$, $\tau$, $\omega$ to 2D variables,

$$\mathrm{STFT}\{x(\pmb{t})\}(\pmb{\tau},\pmb{\omega}) \equiv X(\pmb{\tau}, \pmb{\omega}) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x(\pmb{t}) w(\pmb{t}-\pmb{\tau}) e^{-j <\pmb{\omega},\pmb{ t}>} \, dt $$

where the 2D variables are $\pmb{t} = (t_1,t_2)$, $\pmb{\tau} = (\tau_1,\tau_2)$, $\pmb{\omega} = (\omega_1,\omega_2)$ and $<\cdot,\cdot>$ denotes a scalar product. Hence the results in classicaly 4D.  The answer by [AnonSubmitter85](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/users/5134/anonsubmitter85) separates variables on dimensions 1 and 2 (and is thus called separable), corresponding to the standard scalar product $<\pmb{\omega},\pmb{ t}> = \tau_1*\omega_1+\tau_2\omega_2$. One can use other non-separable, anisotropic kernels or windows $w$, depending on  the applications.